# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Tags: mysql, sql

This is query I am using to insert into the table.

I am getting the error like this

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO userinfo(runnername,runnerdob,runnerage,runnergender,runneraddress,runnercity,runnerstate,runnerpincode,runneremail,runnerpassword,runnermobilenumber,e_name,e_relationship,e_address,e_mobilenumber,height,weight,bloodgroup,category,tshirtsize,accountcreationdate,lastlogin,timestamp,registereduser,ipaddress,status) 
VALUES('$runnername','$dt',$runnerage,'$runnergender','$runneraddress','$runnercity','$runnerstate','$runnerpincode','$runneremail','$epassword','$runnermobilenumber','$e_name','$e_relationship','$e_address','$e_mobilenumber','$height','$weight','$bloodgroup','$category',$tshirtsize,'$accountdate','Y','$t','Y','$ip',1") or die(mysql_error());
```

This is generated output

> INSERT INTO
>   userinfo(runnername,runnerdob,runnerage,runnergender,runneraddress,runnercity,runnerstate,runnerpincode,runneremail,runnerpassword,runnermobilenumber,e_name,e_relationship,e_address,e_mobilenumber,height,weight,bloodgroup,category,tshirtsize,accountcreationdate,lastlogin,timestamp,registereduser,ipaddress,status)
>   VALUES('VIDHYA PRAKASH R','1985-04-08',29,'M','12 DIVINE
>   RESIDENNCY','coimbatore','TAMILNADU','641035','vidhyaprakash85@gmail.com','FU4A31/GhcmRItAHb97lNtrjRZr+y1yG4arxawG/qEs=','9944524864','rajendran','father','12
>   DIVINE RESIDENNCY coimbatore TAMILNADU
>   641035','9894773083','6','6','A1+ve','M',42,'11-07-2014
>   12:11:02','Y','1405060862','Y','127.0.0.1',1)

but I am getting error as

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

I am breaking my head for past two hours.

Any one please help me ?

Comment: Could you please setup SQLFiddle to show you problem? It looks correct, but you probably just missed some column

Comment: Please note that PHP's mysql_ API is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

The issue was at the end of the query, writing long insert queries on single line should be avoided and better to write in multiple lines which helps to find the issue almost immediately , or the best is to use prepared statement with PDO or mysqli.

Your query ends as `'Y','$ip',1")` which was missing `)`

Here how the query should be

```
$sql = mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO userinfo
    (
        runnername,
        runnerdob,
        runnerage,
        runnergender,
        runneraddress,
        runnercity,
        runnerstate,
        runnerpincode,
        runneremail,
        runnerpassword,
        runnermobilenumber,
        e_name,
        e_relationship,
        e_address,
        e_mobilenumber,
        height,
        weight,
        bloodgroup,
        category,
        tshirtsize,
        accountcreationdate,
        lastlogin,
        timestamp,
        registereduser,
        ipaddress,
        status
    ) 
    VALUES
    (
        '$runnername',
        '$dt',
        $runnerage,
        '$runnergender',
        '$runneraddress',
        '$runnercity',
        '$runnerstate',
        '$runnerpincode',
        '$runneremail',
        '$epassword',
        '$runnermobilenumber',
        '$e_name',
        '$e_relationship',
        '$e_address',
        '$e_mobilenumber',
        '$height',
        '$weight',
        '$bloodgroup',
        '$category',
        $tshirtsize,
        '$accountdate',
        'Y',
        '$t',
        'Y',
        '$ip',
        1
    )"
) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a close bracket at the end of your values statement?

Instead of

```
'$ip',1")
```

Shouldn't it be

```
'$ip',1)")
```